# How to: Give SKScene access to dismiss() UIKit method

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is it possible to get access to dismiss() in an SKScene class? Dismiss is a method available from apples UIKit here is a link to Apple's official documentation on [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss).

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

}
```

Attempting to fire dismiss off from an IBAction example:

```
    @IBAction func dismissTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     //figure out how to dismiss
    }
```

Dismiss would normally be used like this -

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dismiss` is a method on UIviewController and not on SKScene.  However, your scene does have a `view` property that is its containing view (which is a `SKView`, which is a `UIView`, which is a `UIResponder`).  You can use the view's `next` method inherited from `UIResponder` to walk up the responder chain until you hit the first view controller (because `UIViewController` is also a `UIResponder`):

```
extension UIResponder {
    func firstParent<T: UIResponder>(ofType type: T.Type ) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next.flatMap { $0.firstParent(ofType: type) }
    }
}
```

```
//Use in your SKScene like so
view?.firstParent(ofType: UIViewController.self)?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you explain this firstParent method a bit more? After adding the extension outside of the class, and adding that line below the func into my IBAction, an : unrecognized selector sent to instance error is thrown.

Comment: EDITED ABOVE. Sorry I left out the .self after UIViewController.  Anyways firstParent recursively walks up the responder chain until it finds the kind of UIResponder you are looking for (typically a UIView or UIViewController), or it hits the window.  It does this is a type safe way using a generic.  You can pass in UIViewController.self or YourViewControllerClass.self depending on what type of object you want to get back.  In this case UIViewController.self is sufficient because dismiss is defined on UIViewController.

Comment: thanks for the update! great answer just wanted to understand it a bit more which I do now so much appreciated. 

After updating the code -

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKView dismissTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf0e814800'`

Comment: do you have an idea why `NSInvalidArgumentException` would be getting fired off here? Investigating now but trying to build this question up with an exceptional answer. Thanks again for the help

Comment: It looks like that's an unrelated error.  Possibly you have a broken outlet in your storyboard or nib called `dismissTapped`?  Open the storyboard/nib and selected the viewController.  then tap on the Connections inspector on the right and see if there is a broken connection for `dismissTapped`